# Strange behavior of corrplot

Tags: r, r-corrplot

With the following R code with the package `corrplot`:

```
library(corrplot)
M <- cor(mtcars)
diag(M) <- 0
dev.new()
corrplot(M, is.corr=F, method = "circle", col=colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","goldenrod"))(256), cl.lim=c(-0.87, 0.91))

L <- M/2
dev.new()
corrplot(L, is.corr=F, method = "circle", col=colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","goldenrod"))(256), cl.lim=c(-0.87, 0.91))
```

I have the two plots (shown below) with two desired properties by using the same color range: 1) the circle size is proportional to the corresponding value, and 2) the diagonals (which are all 0s) are shown as white.

[image]
[image]

However, when I try the following:

```
N <- abs(L)
dev.new()
corrplot(N, is.corr=F, method = "circle", col=colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","goldenrod"))(256), cl.lim=c(-0.87, 0.91))
```

this code does not render a plot (see below) as I wanted: 1) the proportionality does not follow the color range, and 2) the diagonals are not white any more. The colorbar mapping also looks different from the other two plots. Is it because all the values in N are positive? How can I make it to work?

[image]